# Find a common denominator

Tags: integration, fractions, partial-fractions

I'm trying to integrate a function but first I need to find a common denominator for: $\frac{A}{x-8}\ $ + $\frac{B}{x+1}\ $ + $\frac{C}{x-1}\ $

Comment: Did you try multiplying them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{A}{x-8}\ $ + $\frac{B}{x+1}\ $ + $\frac{C}{x-1}\ =\frac{A(x+1)(x-1)+B(x-8)(x-1)+C(x-8)(x+1)}{(x-8)(x+1)(x-1)}$